# XPath with Java - Selecting a text value between subtags

Tags: java, xml, xhtml, xpath

I'm working on this html snippet:

```
<p class="pageSelector">
    <a href="/BlaBla">&lt; Prev</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="/BlaBla">1</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="/BlaBla">2</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="/BlaBla">3</a>&nbsp;
    4&nbsp;
    <a href="/BlaBla">5</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="/BlaBla">6</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="/BlaBla">Next &gt;</a>&nbsp;
</p>
```

rendered (more or less) as *< Prev  1  2  3  **4**  5  6  Next >*  .

I want to select the "4" because I need to discover the 'current' page. Using

```
//p[@class='pageSelector']/text()[normalize-space()]
```

(tested with Firefox XPath Ckecker) I thougth I'd solved but no, because I obtained 7 matches.

Anyone please could tell me where I'm wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

normalize-space removes whitespace, but the no-break-space character (despite its visual appearance) is not considered to be whitespace for this purpose. So I would do

```
text()[translate(., '&#x20;&#x09;&#x0a;&#x0d;&#xa0;', '')]
```

which will return you those child text nodes that contain a character other than whitespace or no-break-space; you may then need to process this further to extract the part of the content you want.

Comment: I used this approach and further replaced all non-number chars with a regular expression. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

if your using xslt you could apply a further template onto the a tags using

```
<xsl:template match="p[@class='pageSelector']/a/text()[normalize-space()]">
</xsl:template>
```

this will mean that your left with just the 4

Comment: That's just wrong. `ParentNode`? Even then `4&nbsp;` has `p` as an immediate ancestor.

Comment: oops sorry forgot to remove it was playing around!

Comment: yea what im trying to explain is that if he uses both templates this one will apply nothing to the a elements text, so then his template will only leave the 4!